# Success redirect to profile form gives TypeError at /profile/ join() - argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-2.2

I have an extended User model called UserProfile, and the update view uses the SuccessMessageMixin to redirect on successful update. The problem is that something in the django code is trying to join an unset var (paths) to the path, and I'm not sure why.

**user_profile/views.py**

```
class UserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("user_profile:profile")
    # success_url = "/success/"
    success_message = "Profile updated"

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

**Stack trace on submit of form with changed data** (the data does actually get updated, so this is purely a redisplay issue).

```
File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\ntpath.py" in join
  89.         for p in map(os.fspath, paths):

During handling of the above exception (expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py" in dispatch
  52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\users\mjnic\OneDrive\Workspaces\Django\pyp\src\pyp\user_profile\views.py" in post
  30.         return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  15.             return engine.get_template(template_name)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in get_template
  34.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in get_template
  143.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in find_template
  125.                 template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py" in get_template
  18.         for origin in self.get_template_sources(template_name):

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py" in get_template_sources
  36.                 name = safe_join(template_dir, template_name)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py" in safe_join
  32.     final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\ntpath.py" in join
  115.         genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)

File "C:\Users\mjnic\.virtualenvs\pyp-E_0Se9Bl\lib\genericpath.py" in _check_arg_types
  149.                             (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None

Exception Type: TypeError at /profile/
Exception Value: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'
```

What am I missing? According to docs it should be enough to set success_url, and the "/profile/" link is all that is required, since nobody can maintain another users profile (i.e. there is no pk, slug etc. required in the url)

Comment: You did not specify a `template`.

Comment: Furthermore please do *not* render a response in case of a succesful POST.

Comment: It's using a form that inherits UserChangeForm, so the template is automatically set to userprofile_form.html.

Comment: If I take that render out, then I get an error `The view user_profile.views.UserProfileView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` - now I'm a little confused - what am I supposed to render here?

Comment: Really you shouldn't be defining `post` at all. UpdateView will handle that for you.

Comment: Ah, OK. That was it - if I remove the post method it all works nicely. I guess I was doubling up on something django was already doing behind the scenes and confusing it. Thanks :)

Comment: @urbanspaceman: Django uses `get_template_names()`: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_template_names this will indeed add a template name based on the model of your object. `self.template_name` does *not*, that is simply the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing *too* much yourself. You should let the Django [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) perform the boilerplate code. This will call the [**`get_template_names()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) that will then indeed return `app/modelname_form.html` as template name. So do *not* override the `post` method:

```
class UserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_profile:profile')
    success_message = 'Profile updated'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user

    # no post method override
```